# JNI -> how to wrap c++ void*

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have c++ function that take `void*` as parameter. How to wrap it in java?

C++

```
void foo(void* data)
{
}
```

Java

```
void foo(Object[] data)
{
}
```

I'm not sure. Please help.

Comment: What is `data` supposed to contain?

Comment: Virtually anything, array of elements.

Comment: So closest in java is a `byte` array? You're missing to know the actual length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think (I'm not so well versed in the language) of in java code is

```
void foo(Byte[] data) {
}
```

Though you don't know the actual size of the byte array, this needs to be clear from the `foo()` function called via JNI.

Answer (score 1):

If by "wrap it in java", you mean "call it from Java", you need to create a java class, and declare a native method.  Static is easier unless you want to pass the java object as a parameter:

```
package my.package;
public class Foo {
public static native void foo(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Second, run javah on the class file.  It will produce a C header like:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class net_redpoint_utils_Scratch */

#ifndef _Included_net_redpoint_utils_Scratch
#define _Included_net_redpoint_utils_Scratch
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     my_package_Scratch
 * Method:    foo
 * Signature: ([B)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_Scratch_foo
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

You need to implement that function, using exactly the same name, signature, etc.  The jbyteArray is the JNI type for the byte[] argument.

PS: check out SWIG